# reseting password not working in KVM guest

Tags: vps, kvm-virtualization, chroot, password-reset, virsh

I lost the root password for a guest system.

I mounted the guest system and changed it to single user mode. Then I used `virsh` console to access the guest system, which was now in single user mode, and used a command `echo "root":"123456" | chpasswd` to reset the password.

However, after the guest system rebooted, I couldn't access it. The new password was incorrect (`Login incorrect`). However, if I mount the guest system again in host, and call `chroot`, I verified that the new password was working by switching to a regular account, and switching back to root and entered the new password.

Both the server version and guest version of OS are the latest centos version.

Comment: What do the logs in the guest tell you?

Comment: Jun  6 17:15:37 guest34 kernel: type=1400 audit(1370564137.621:16): avc:  denied  { read } for  pid=1057 comm="login" name="passwd" dev=vda1 ino=18194 scontext=system_u:system_r:local_login_t:s0-s0:c0.c1023 tcontext=system_u:object_r:file_t:s0 tclass=file

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You've posted an SELinux denial, wherein `login` is being denied access to read `/etc/passwd`. From looking at the log entry I can see that it has an invalid security context (it should be `passwd_file_t`, not `file_t`; did you manually edit this file?).

I recommend you fix the security context on `/etc/passwd` (and the rest of the system just to be safe).

To fix invalid security contexts, `chroot` back into the filesystem and then run:

```
restorecon -r -v /
```

If this fails (e.g. because SELinux is not running in your chroot) then

```
touch /.autorelabel
```

and reboot the VM, to have it relabeled at the next reboot.

Comment: Thanks, it's fixed after running 'restorecon -r -v /' in single user mode. Here's the restoring log: 
restorecon reset /etc/shadow context system_u:object_r:file_t:s0->system_u:object_r:shadow_t:s0
restorecon reset /etc/passwd context system_u:object_r:file_t:s0->system_u:object_r:etc_t:s0

Comment: Close enough. Remember to mark the question as solved by clicking the outline of the check mark next to the answer that resolved the problem for you.

Comment: The next question is why would linux read /etc/passwd file when I try login?

Comment: Because it has all the information about your user account, like your uid and gid and home directory.